# syncfusion xamarin form button control, click event not fired on IOS simulator but fired on my IPHONE

Tags: xamarin, syncfusion

I am using syncfusion xamarin form button control on my project,  the click event didn't fire on the IOS simulator but fired on both my IPHONE and IPAD.  anyone experienced this issue?

the XMAL is attached below,

```
<buttons:SfButton Padding="10"
                            x:Name="btnCamera"
                            Grid.Column="1"   
                            IsCheckable="False"
                            BackgroundColor="White"
                            BorderColor="Transparent"
                            BorderWidth="0"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            Clicked="btnCamera_Clicked"
                            HasShadow="True"
                            CornerRadius="20">
            <buttons:SfButton.Content>
                <Image Source="Camera.png" 
                                    HeightRequest="45" 
                                    WidthRequest="45"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            </buttons:SfButton.Content>
        </buttons:SfButton>
        <buttons:SfButton Padding="10"
                            x:Name="btnImageFolder"
                            Grid.Column="3"   
                            IsCheckable="False"
                            BackgroundColor="White"
                            BorderColor="Transparent"
                            BorderWidth="0"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            Clicked="btnImageFolder_Clicked"
                            HasShadow="True"
                            CornerRadius="20">
            <buttons:SfButton.Content>
                <Image Source="ImageFolder.png" 
                                    HeightRequest="45" 
                                    WidthRequest="45"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            </buttons:SfButton.Content>
        </buttons:SfButton>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Certain questions here are more likely to get helpful answers. Questions that don’t show what you’ve tried are generally more difficult to answer - people often skip right over them. So show your code for best results. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, we can help with that, and we want to - that’s part of why we’re here. To learn more about helping us help you, please start with [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you’re really ambitious, read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query: StackOverflow : syncfusion xamarin form button control, click event not fired on IOS simulator but fired on my IPHONE

We are unable to replicate the reported issue on our side. We are prepared a sample based on the provided code snippet since the ButtonClick event is properly called on our side. We have prepared a sample and video for your reference. [Sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Button_Sample-655619563)

Please make sure you have added SfButtonRenderer for iOS in the AppDelagates.cs file. Refer to the below link,

Link: https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/button/gettingstarted#additional-step-for-ios

Please check and let us know once the problem was resolved on your side.

Regards,
Ruba Shanmugam

Comment: thank you Ruba, your suggestion ->added SfButtonRenderer for iOS in the AppDelagates.cs file works.